# C: Resolving segmentation fault due to possibly insufficient memory

Tags: c

I am coming up against a segmentation fault in my code that I can only explain through insufficient available memory. What is happening is that I am trying to create a `NxN` matrix where `N` is a large number. For `N=8`, the programme runs fine, but for `N>=16³=5000`, I get a segmentation fault automatically. This is ew Is there any simple way of solving this problem? I actually want to simulate sizes of the range `N=64³` if possible, so this is a very essential question for me.

My code structure is as follows.

```
const int N=16**3;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
double rnorm[N][N];
...
}

void Diluisci(..., double rnorm[N][N]{
...
AdjMatOnestep(rnorm);
}

void AdjMatOnestep(double rnorm[][N]){
...}
```

So `main()` calls `Diluisci()` which calls `AdjMatOnestep()`, and as soon as I call this last function, I get a segmentation fault. I don't even enter into the first line of it. DDD says "error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address ...".

Any ideas?

Comment: Most CPU architectures have a pretty small limit on the size of stack frames, so you can't allocate huge local arrays.

Comment: `const int N=16**3;` ??

Comment: There is no `**` operator in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to allocate `rnorm` on the stack, but at 8 bytes for each of the 4096 * 4096 elements, that comes to about 128 MB. There probably isn't enough room on the stack for that amount of storage.

You should use `malloc()` to create this array on the heap instead.

Comment: Would you please mind explaining the difference between the heap and the stack?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for providing solutions to problems, it is not for educating you on elementary issues that you can very easily look up by yourself.